# How can I convert time to UTC in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am getting time with timezone from an API.

Example: 2019-06-25T08:01:32-05:00

How can I change to UTC time using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes:

```
// this date format will consider the timezone '-05:00'
$dt = new DateTime('2019-06-25T08:01:32-05:00');
// then you convert it to utc
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('utc'));

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // will give you 2019-06-25 13:01:32
```

Manual DateTime: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Manual DateTimeZone: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php